# Can I disable Hyper-V feature if I have Docker installed

Tags: docker, hyper-v, hypervisor

I have installed Docker on Windows10 to work with single-node Hadoop cluster and enabled Hyper-V feature for it. Now I don't need it, but I don't want to drop docker containers. Can I disable Hyper-V feature for some time and enable it, when I need to work with docker again? Or it might somehow affect existing containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker is heavily built on deep Linux kernel features which Windows does not support (such as cgroups and namespaces) which is why Docker on Windows 10 can use one of 2 backends:
Hyper-V or WSL2 which in turn is also based on Hyper-V.

It is possible, although not recommended to setup a Windows container on a Windows host without using Hyper-V basing on windows process isolation. This seems to be irrelevant to your case as you ask about Hadoop cluster which seems to be supported only on linux.
So it seems that even if you manage to setup docker to work without Hyper-V, setting up an Hadoop cluster will be impossible.

What is you concern? Is it about performance? Why would you like to turn Hyper-V off?

Comment: I'm worried about performance. On docker, I have a Linux container that has Hadoop installed. I'm not sure that I will need it in the near future, but I don't want to delete it, I just want to turn off Hyper-V so as not to overload the system. I don't use the container all the time, only start it when needed, and I don't plan on starting it when Hyper-V is disabled.

Comment: There is no reason to worry about performance, Windows machines with windows 11 have Hyper-V enabled by default (Mostly for security reasons). As long as you have an 8th generation Intel cpu and higher or it's equivalent, having Hyper-V on has a very low overhead.
Another reason not to turn Hyper-V off and on is that it requires a reboot. Anyway, from an experiment I made, my container was not deleted after turning Hyper-V off and back on, but I would not recommend trying it yourself as I do not know if this behavior is guaranteed by Docker.